# Bluetooth keeps changing from A2dp to headset and loses connection on Debian Buster with JBL 4 Speaker

Tags: debian, connectivity

since over a year I am having trouble with the bluetooth connection to my JBL 4 speaker. It looses connection again and again. I created a script according to what I found on the internet to reconnect via keyboard short cut. Sometimes it is connected with it within a view seconds sometimes I had to open PulseAudio to switch from off to A2P. This I have to do then multiple times.
Forgive me if I might not use the correct terms because I do not know if it is loosing the connection or just switches the profile.
I recently  upgraded from Stretch to Buster. This made it a bit more stable but it is still not reliable.
I did try reading the logfiles and searched for the errors in it but with no satisfying result.
What I already did:
According to https://askubuntu.com/questions/934381/bluetooth-speaker-not-doing-a2dp-ubuntu-gnome-17-04/935972
Insert in /var/lib/gdm3/.config/pulse/default.pa:

```
#!/usr/bin/pulseaudio -nF
#

# load system wide configuration
.include /etc/pulse/default.pa
### unload driver modules for Bluetooth hardware
.ifexists module-bluetooth-policy.so
  unload-module module-bluetooth-policy
.endif

.ifexists module-bluetooth-discover.so
  unload-module module-bluetooth-discover
.endif
```

I changed the /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

```
[General]

Disable=Headset
AutoConnect=true
Enable=Source,Sink,Media,Control,Gateway
Disable=Socket
#Default adapter name
# Defaults to 'BlueZ X.YZ'
#Name = BlueZ
HFP=false

[A2DP]
SBCSources=1
MPEG12Sources=0

# Default device class. Only the major and minor device class bits are
# considered. Defaults to '0x000000'.
#Class = 0x000100

# How long to stay in discoverable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 180, i.e. 3 minutes.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay discoverable forever
# DiscoverableTimeout = 0

# How long to stay in pairable mode before going back to non-discoverable
# The value is in seconds. Default is 0.
# 0 = disable timer, i.e. stay pairable forever
# PairableTimeout = 0

# Automatic connection for bonded devices driven by platform/user events.
# If a platform plugin uses this mechanism, automatic connections will be
# enabled during the interval defined below. Initially, this feature
# intends to be used to establish connections to ATT channels. Default is 60.
#AutoConnectTimeout = 01

# Use vendor id source (assigner), vendor, product and version information for
# DID profile support. The values are separated by ":" and assigner, VID, PID
# and version.
# Possible vendor id source values: bluetooth, usb (defaults to usb)
#DeviceID = bluetooth:30:C0:1B:20:7F:04

# Do reverse service discovery for previously unknown devices that connect to
# us. This option is really only needed for qualification since the BITE tester
# doesn't like us doing reverse SDP for some test cases (though there could in
# theory be other useful purposes for this too). Defaults to 'true'.
#ReverseServiceDiscovery = true

# Enable name resolving after inquiry. Set it to 'false' if you don't need
# remote devices name and want shorter discovery cycle. Defaults to 'true'.
# NameResolving = false

# Enable runtime persistency of debug link keys. Default is false which
# makes debug link keys valid only for the duration of the connection
# that they were created for.
#DebugKeys = false

# Restricts all controllers to the specified transport. Default value
# is "dual", i.e. both BR/EDR and LE enabled (when supported by the HW).
# Possible values: "dual", "bredr", "le"
ControllerMode = bredr

# Enables Multi Profile Specification support. This allows to specify if
# system supports only Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) configuration
# or both Multiple Profiles Single Device (MPSD) and Multiple Profiles Multiple
# Devices (MPMD) configurations.
# Possible values: "off", "single", "multiple"
MultiProfile = multiple

# Permanently enables the Fast Connectable setting for adapters that
# support it. When enabled other devices can connect faster to us,
# however the tradeoff is increased power consumptions. This feature
# will fully work only on kernel version 4.1 and newer. Defaults to
# 'false'.
FastConnectable = true

# Default privacy setting.
# Enables use of private address.
# Possible values: "off", "device", "network"
# "network" option not supported currently
# Defaults to "off"
# Privacy = off


[Policy]
#
# The ReconnectUUIDs defines the set of remote services that should try
# to be reconnected to in case of a link loss (link supervision
# timeout). The policy plugin should contain a sane set of values by
# default, but this list can be overridden here. By setting the list to
# empty the reconnection feature gets disabled.
#ReconnectUUIDs=00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb,0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb

# ReconnectAttempts define the number of attempts to reconnect after a link
# lost. Setting the value to 0 disables reconnecting feature.
ReconnectAttempts=7

# ReconnectIntervals define the set of intervals in seconds to use in between
# attempts.
# If the number of attempts defined in ReconnectAttempts is bigger than the
# set of intervals the last interval is repeated until the last attempt.
#ReconnectIntervals=1,2,4,8,16,32,64
ReconnectIntervals=1


# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
# This includes adapters present on start as well as adapters that are plugged
# in later on. Defaults to 'false'.
AutoEnable=true
```

My script does this:

echo "power on\nagent on\ndefault-agent \npair $MAC_address \ntrust $MAC_address \nconnect $MAC_address\t \nquit" | bluetoothctl

I changed so many things that I cannot remember what anymore.

My system is

- OS - debian 10.3 (x86-64)
- Cinnamon - 3.8.8
- Linux Kernel - 4.9.0-8amd64

Anything with "blue"

- blueman/stable,now 2.0.8-1 amd64
- bluetooth/stable,stable,now 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 all
- bluez-cups/stable,now 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 amd64
- bluez-firmware/stable,stable,now 1.2-4 all
- bluez-hcidump/stable,now 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 amd64
- bluez-obexd/stable,now 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 amd64
- bluez-test-scripts/stable,stable,now 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 all
- bluez-test-tools/stable,now 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 amd64
- bluez-tools/stable,now 2.0~20170911.0.7cb788c-2 amd64
- bluez/stable,now 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 amd64
- gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0/stable,now 3.28.2-4~deb10u1 amd64
- gnome-bluetooth/stable,now 3.28.2-4~deb10u1 amd64
- libbluetooth3/stable,now 5.50-1.2~deb10u1 amd64
- libgnome-bluetooth13/stable,now 3.28.2-4~deb10u1 amd64
- pulseaudio-module-bluetooth/buster-backports,now 13.0-3~bpo10+1 amd64
- Pavucontrol - 3.0-4 amd64

USB Adapter

- Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

An extract via

> grep "blue" /var/log/syslog

but only a part of it because of character restrictions you will see below:

```
Feb 29 00:17:36 debian bluetoothd[937]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.217 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 00:17:36 debian bluetoothd[937]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.217 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unknown group A2DP in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unknown key Disable for group General in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unknown key AutoConnect for group General in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unknown key Enable for group General in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unknown key Disable for group General in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unknown key HFP for group General in /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Starting SDP server
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Feb 29 06:32:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Feb 29 06:32:39 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582954359.9829] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.14.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Feb 29 06:32:40 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582954360.0086] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
Feb 29 06:32:40 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582954360.0137] bluez5: NAP: added interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 06:33:55 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 06:33:55 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 06:33:59 debian dbus-daemon[1646]: [session uid=1000 pid=1646] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez.obex' unit='obex.service' requested by ':1.58' (uid=1000 pid=1929 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/blueman-applet ")
Feb 29 06:33:59 debian dbus-daemon[1646]: [session uid=1000 pid=1646] Successfully activated service 'org.bluez.obex'
Feb 29 06:34:00 debian cinnamon[1866]: JS LOG: [LookingGlass/info] Adding indicator: blueman
Feb 29 06:35:05 debian bluetoothd[939]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_30_C0_1B_20_7F_04/fd0: fd(36) ready
Feb 29 06:35:21 debian bluetoothd[939]: Suspend: Connection timed out (110)
Feb 29 06:35:21 debian bluetoothd[939]: SUSPEND request rejected: Bad State (49)
Feb 29 06:36:05 debian bluetoothd[939]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_30_C0_1B_20_7F_04/fd1: fd(36) ready
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582954850.3318] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/AppIndicator.py:8: PyGIWarning: AppIndicator3 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/GameControllerWakelock.py", line 36, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/SerialManager.py", line 61, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 06:40:50 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 06:40:51 debian bluetoothd[939]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Feb 29 06:40:51 debian bluetoothd[939]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Feb 29 06:40:51 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582954851.4436] bluez5: NAP: added interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 06:40:51 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 06:40:51 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 06:40:53 debian bluetoothd[939]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_30_C0_1B_20_7F_04/fd2: fd(37) ready
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582959204.3603] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/GameControllerWakelock.py", line 36, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/SerialManager.py", line 61, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 07:53:24 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 07:53:25 debian bluetoothd[939]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Feb 29 07:53:25 debian bluetoothd[939]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Feb 29 07:53:25 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582959205.4896] bluez5: NAP: added interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 07:53:25 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 07:53:25 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 07:53:32 debian bluetoothd[939]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_30_C0_1B_20_7F_04/fd3: fd(37) ready
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582959514.0113] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 212, in Run
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/DiscvManager.py", line 92, in on_adapter_removed
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/GameControllerWakelock.py", line 36, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/SerialManager.py", line 61, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 07:58:34 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 07:58:35 debian bluetoothd[939]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Feb 29 07:58:35 debian bluetoothd[939]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Feb 29 07:58:35 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582959515.1173] bluez5: NAP: added interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 07:58:35 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 07:58:35 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 07:58:55 debian bluetoothd[939]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_30_C0_1B_20_7F_04/fd4: fd(37) ready
Feb 29 08:40:38 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 29 08:40:38 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 212, in Run
Feb 29 08:40:38 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/DiscvManager.py", line 92, in on_adapter_removed
Feb 29 08:40:38 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 08:40:38 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/GameControllerWakelock.py", line 36, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 08:40:38 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 08:40:38 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 08:40:38 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 08:40:38 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 08:40:39 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 08:40:39 debian bluetoothd[939]: send: Software caused connection abort (103)
Feb 29 08:40:39 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 08:40:39 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/SerialManager.py", line 61, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 08:40:39 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 08:40:39 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 08:40:39 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 08:40:39 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 08:40:39 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 08:40:39 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582962038.8883] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 08:40:40 debian bluetoothd[939]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Feb 29 08:40:40 debian bluetoothd[939]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Feb 29 08:40:40 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582962040.0044] bluez5: NAP: added interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 08:40:40 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 08:40:40 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 08:41:03 debian bluetoothd[939]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_30_C0_1B_20_7F_04/fd5: fd(36) ready
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582963124.2621] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 212, in Run
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/DiscvManager.py", line 92, in on_adapter_removed
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/GameControllerWakelock.py", line 36, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/SerialManager.py", line 61, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 08:58:44 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 08:58:45 debian bluetoothd[939]: Sap driver initialization failed.
Feb 29 08:58:45 debian bluetoothd[939]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
Feb 29 08:58:45 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582963125.3800] bluez5: NAP: added interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 08:58:45 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 08:58:45 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 08:59:16 debian bluetoothd[939]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_30_C0_1B_20_7F_04/fd6: fd(36) ready
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian bluetoothd[939]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian bluetoothd[939]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.199 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian NetworkManager[943]: <info>  [1582963183.6143] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 00:0A:CD:32:33:60
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 212, in Run
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/DiscvManager.py", line 92, in on_adapter_removed
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/GameControllerWakelock.py", line 36, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 55, in wrapper
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/SerialManager.py", line 61, in on_device_property_changed
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/main/Device.py", line 48, in __init__
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 148, in warp
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/errors.py", line 146, in warp
Feb 29 08:59:43 debian /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1929]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/PropertiesBlueZInterface.py", line 34, in get_properties
```

Thank you for any help.

ciao,

Micha

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by using another bluetooth adapter.
With the "Priva III" from Avantree the connection has not got lost again. It worked right after plugin.

Comment: Hello. How that bluetooth adapter is different from the one you used?

Comment: Hi Roman, my old one (Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle) was a simple unintelligent sender and receiver. The new one (Avantree Priva III ) is, as far as I understood only a sender with some intelligence within. As soon as it get power to it it connects with my JBL box. Thats might be the difference. I am not so deep in it. I hope it helps a bit... ciao, Micha